# copy the output of an executed command by the system() call to a char array

Tags: c, linux, datetime

Is it possible to copy the output of a command used on `system()` function on Linux? E.g., If I run

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    char date[8]; //e.g., 20130421 yyyymmdd
    char time[4]; // e.g., 0204 hhmm
    system("ntpdate");
    return 0;
}
```

it outputs:

`21 Apr 02:12:56 ntpdate[32680]: no servers can be used, exiting`

is it possible to copy the output to a string? how can I copy the date and time info to a char array e.g. `char *date` ; `char *time` on C?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`system` does not allow such a thing, you have to use `popen("ntpdate", "r")`, which returns a `FILE *` from which you can read the command output.